# solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory removes & at index time but not at query time

Tags: solr, filter, ampersand

I am new to Solr and I have a case where at index time, a value (text field) is analyzed by the solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory like so:

```
<filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" preserveOriginal="1"/>
```

Running this solr admin analysis tool it shows me this removes the ampersand. Reading the documentation this would be because of generateWordParts="1" as it sees the ampersand as a delimiter.

Having this filter run on query time I expected the same result but it does not remove the ampersand.

Hence when searching for "Adam & Eve" it will not be found.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Can you please include the full fieldType definition from your schema.xml for the field where you are seeing this?

Comment: If possible, post the request handler definition too